# Autosize very long text inside jumbotron class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have very long string (`e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` and similar) that need to be shown inside `col-md-8` jumbotron class of bootstrap 3. Problem is that last few characters of string are outside the jumbotron box.

Nothing inside css is changed, bootstrap is used as is out of box...

My question is, how to make this text (that can be even longer) to fit inside jumbotron box?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to use would be the word-break property and make the word wrap onto two lines:

```
p.whatever {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

These are the vendor prefixes if you need them:

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;

// Non standard for webkit
word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```